# HyperLink in Cells DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I want to know how to add a link to the values of a column that send you to the info all of that lots, the green parts of the picture are where I applied a values template, I'm using a PivotGridField like this:
*THIS IS JUST FOR TEST* to see what happens, I'm new using devexpress

```
<ValueTemplate>
                                     <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="Linked" NavigateUrl="HTTP://GOOGLE.COM" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" ForeColor="Green" BackColor="Black" Text='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.Text)? "&nbsp;": Container.Text%>'>

                                    </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                               </ValueTemplate>
```

the matter is that its doesn't apply to the values only the headers, in the case of the fields 'Location' and 'Area' is the only where the values take the effect, here is my code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 1800px; height: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxPivotGrid ID="pivotSummary" runat="server" DataSourceID="AgingDataSource" ClientInstanceName="summaryPivot" l>
                       <Fields>

                          <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldSummaryArea" Area="RowArea" AreaIndex="0" FieldName="Area" SortMode="Value" SortBySummaryInfo-FieldName="AreaOrder" SortBySummaryInfo-SummaryType="Max">
                              <ValueStyle CssClass="headerRow"></ValueStyle>

                               <ValueTemplate>
                                     <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="Linked" NavigateUrl="HTTP://GOOGLE.COM" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" ForeColor="Green" BackColor="Black" Text='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.Text)? "&nbsp;": Container.Text%>'>
                                      <%--<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {                                                                       
                                                    var parameter = s.GetText();    
                                                    RawDataGrid.PerformCallback(parameter);
                                                    RawDataWindow.Show();
                                                    }" />--%>
                                    </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                               </ValueTemplate>

                          </dx:PivotGridField>

                          <dx:PivotGridField ID="fielSummaryLocation" Area="RowArea" AreaIndex="0" FieldName="Location">
                              <ValueStyle CssClass="headerRow"></ValueStyle>

                              <ValueTemplate>
                                     <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="Linked" NavigateUrl="HTTP://GOOGLE.COM" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" ForeColor="Green" BackColor="Black" Text='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.Text)? "&nbsp;": Container.Text%>'>
                                      <%--<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {                                                                       
                                                    var parameter = s.GetText();    
                                                    RawDataGrid.PerformCallback(parameter);
                                                    RawDataWindow.Show();
                                                    }" />--%>
                                    </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                               </ValueTemplate>

                          </dx:PivotGridField>

                          <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldSummaryRange" Area="ColumnArea" AreaIndex="0" FieldName="Range" Caption="Group" SortMode="Value" SortBySummaryInfo-FieldName="RangeOrder" SortBySummaryInfo-SummaryType="Max">
                              <ValueStyle CssClass="headerRow"></ValueStyle>

                              <ValueTemplate>
                                     <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="Linked" NavigateUrl="HTTP://GOOGLE.COM" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" ForeColor="Green" BackColor="Black" Text='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.Text)? "&nbsp;": Container.Text%>'>

                                    </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                               </ValueTemplate>

                          </dx:PivotGridField>

                          <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldSummaryLotsCount" Area="DataArea" AreaIndex="0" Caption="Lots Count" FieldName="LotsCount" >

                              <ValueTemplate>
                                     <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="Linked" NavigateUrl="HTTP://GOOGLE.COM" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" ForeColor="Green" BackColor="Black" Text='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.Text)? "&nbsp;": Container.Text%>'>
                                      <%--<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {                                                                       
                                                    var parameter = s.GetText();    
                                                    RawDataGrid.PerformCallback(parameter);
                                                    RawDataWindow.Show();
                                                    }" />--%>
                                    </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                               </ValueTemplate>

                           </dx:PivotGridField>

                          <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldSummaryVolumeSum" Area="DataArea" AreaIndex="1" Caption="Volume" FieldName="VolumeSum">

                              <ValueTemplate>
                                     <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="Linked" NavigateUrl="HTTP://GOOGLE.COM" runat="server" Cursor="pointer" ForeColor="Green" BackColor="Black" Text='<%#String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.Text)? "&nbsp;": Container.Text%>'>
                                      <%--<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {                                                                       
                                                    var parameter = s.GetText();    
                                                    RawDataGrid.PerformCallback(parameter);
                                                    RawDataWindow.Show();
                                                    }" />--%>
                                    </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                               </ValueTemplate>

                          </dx:PivotGridField>

                      </Fields>

                         <OptionsView ShowColumnGrandTotalHeader="True" ShowColumnGrandTotals="True" ShowColumnHeaders="False" ShowColumnTotals="True" ShowContextMenus="False" ShowDataHeaders="False" ShowFilterHeaders="False" ShowRowGrandTotalHeader="True" ShowRowGrandTotals="True" ShowRowTotals="True"  />
                            <OptionsPager Position="Bottom" RowsPerPage="20" Visible="False" ></OptionsPager>
                              <Styles> <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerRow" /> </Styles>
                </dx:ASPxPivotGrid>
            </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I marked in red where I want the links to show a brief description of that lots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpSL4.png)

Comment: How come this is related to SQL-Server? please use tags properly.

Comment: All information is taken from a T-SQL stored procedure.

Comment: Doesn't matter. There is no SQL related to your question